# Site to Site VPN with Remote Access VPN

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn, point-to-site-vpn

I would like to apologize in advance as I'm new to the whole VPN thingy.

Currently my company network has been setup with a simple Remote Access VPN done on the router by my predecessor. The purpose is to access company files from offsite.

As we are expanding to another office soon, my boss has tasked me to give the new office access to our company network.I was reading up about the different kinds of VPN and have decided that a site to site VPN would be better for our case.

I am wondering if it was possible to have the Remote Access VPN running concurrently with the Site to Site VPN service? Or even combine them to one service?

I have yet to look at software or hardware solutioning so any additional advice on the matter is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that VPN technologies are tools, each of which has a most appropriate set of uses.

So  I use one technology for site-to-site VPNs (almost invariably IPSec) but a different one (usually, but not always, OpenVPN) for remote access VPNs.  For me, and my user communities, this works well.

Answer (score 0):

A hardware VPN is a great choice for a site to site VPN. I am a big fan of Cisco Meraki gear, the cloud management console means it is a point and click VPN config. No more IOS for VPN config. The Meraki can do both client and site to site.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned a router, yes, it should be possible. You should be able to do an EIGRP tunnel to act as link to your secondary site or configure a Site-to-Site IPsec VPN, while maintaining the already configured remote access VPN.

You can find an example of Site-to-site VPN [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/cloud-systems-management/configuration-professional/113337-ccp-vpn-routerA-routerB-config-00.html).

Comment: EIGRP tunnel? Is there such a thing?

Comment: EIGRP over GRE tunnel, to be precise.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense now - assumes though that the OP is on Cisco routers and wants to use dynamic routing. If it's a simple setup then static routes down the tunnel might do better.

Comment: I use such a method and I keep static routes as an emergency overwrite solution, in case the other end of the line decides to route too much instead of only what's needed. I've seen cases of even /8 classes fully routed which of course caused then internet access problems with all destinations within the routed classes, so statics fix works great and quite fast if needed.